# Yajra Datatable get name by id laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

Here's my car index blade code :

```
@extends('layout.master')
@section('content')
<div id="content" class="content"> 
<h1 class="page-header">Car <small>panel</small></h1>
@include('partials.message')
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-inverse" data-sortable-id="ui-general-1">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-heading-btn">
                <a href="{{ route('car.create') }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</a>
            </div>
            <h4 class="panel-title">Car</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="datatable" style="width: 100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Car Category</th>
                        <th>Year</th>
                        <th>Color</th>
                        <th>Plate No</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="filterRow" class="hidden-xs">
                        <th class="text-center"></th>
                        <th class="text-center"></th>
                        <th class="text-center"></th>
                        <th class="text-center"></th>
                        <th class="text-center"></th>
                        <th class="text-center"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-icon btn-circle btn-success btn-scroll-to-top fade" data-click="scroll-top"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a>
</div>
@include('partials.modalDelete')
</div>
@endsection
@push('pageRelatedJs')
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var datatable = $('#datatable').DataTable(
{
    dom: "lfrtip",
    responsive: true,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url:  "{{ route('car.list') }}",
        data: { '_token' : '{{csrf_token() }}'},
        type: 'POST',
    },
    columns: [
    { data: 'car_category_id', name: 'car_category_id', className: 'text-center',},
    { data: 'year', name: 'year', className: 'text-center', },
    { data: 'color', name: 'color', className: 'text-center', },
    { data: 'plate_no', name: 'plate_no', className: 'text-center', },
    { data: 'status', name: 'status', className: 'text-center', },
    { data: 'action', name: 'action', className: 'text-center', orderable: false, searchable: false  },
    ],
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every(function () {
            $('#datatable thead tr#filterRow th:not(:last-child)').each( function () {
                var title = $('#datatable thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
                $(this).html( '<input type="text" class="col-md-12" placeholder="Search by '+title+'" />');
            });  
            $("#datatable thead input").on('keyup change', function () {
                datatable.column( $(this).parent().index()).search(this.value).draw();
            });
        });
    }
}); 
});
</script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/modal_delete.js') }}"></script>
@endpush
```

How can I get the `car_category [name]` by Id.

> Note: 2 tables car_category and car

**Ex:** *I have 2 categories, 1.suv 2.sport. and I want to add a new car, when I submit it, it shows id instead of name. any idea ?*